# 2 web sites running on same port and without host header

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

I have created a web application on port 443 https and configured to use windows authentication and without any host headers, providing no host header is requirement for Apps development, I have extended this web application on extranet on same port 443 and https and without any host headers, as expected IIS has stopped 1 web site because both are using blank host header and same port.

Can I create 2 IIS sites on same port without any host header by using a wildcard certificate? or nay other solution?

Comment: You need to have different bindings on the different IIS sites. Else IIS will not know where to send your requests that is why one site is stopped.

Comment: Is there any solution to that problem? Will SSL certificate help me?

Comment: No, certificate will not help. The solution is that you need to have different bindings in IIS. Be it different IP addresses, Host names and/or ports.

Answer (score 1):

To host more than one Web site on a Web server, you can assign a unique IP address to each Web site, designate a non-standard TCP port number for a Web site, or use host headers.

Their is no alternative solution and you have to adopt either one of the solution.

Why you want to host 2 sites on same Port without Host header?

Comment: I have 1 web application running on port 443 with windows authentication enabled and using default zone, I want to extend it to have an extranet zone with forms authentication, I don't want to use host headers onweb applications because all site collections in the web application will have their own host name using HNSC methodology.